# Start Kivy app horizontally on android phone

Tags: python, kivy, game-development

I'm new to Kivy and am trying to make a game that will load and play horizontally on an android phone no matter which direction the phone is oriented. Is there an easy way to do that? I looked through the Kivy documentation as well as some other sites & didn't find much. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using `buildozer`, I think that is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the landscape orientation in the buildozer.spec file.

`# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all) orientation = landscape`

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Worked great. Thanks!